# Replace all elements of NumPy array that are greater than some value

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, replace, conditional-statements

I have a 2D NumPy array. How do I replace all values in it greater than a threshold `T = 255` with a value `x = 255`? A slow for-loop based method would be:

```
# arr = arr.copy()  # Optionally, do not modify original arr.

for i in range(arr.shape[0]):
    for j in range(arr.shape[1]):
        if arr[i, j] > 255:
            arr[i, j] = x
```

Comment: For more information, take a look at [this intro to indexing](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html).

Answer (score 462, accepted):

I think both the fastest and most concise way to do this is to use NumPy's built-in Fancy indexing. If you have an `ndarray` named `arr`, you can replace all elements `>255` with a value `x` as follows:

```
arr[arr > 255] = x
```

I ran this on my machine with a 500 x 500 random matrix, replacing all values >0.5 with 5, and it took an average of 7.59ms.

```
In [1]: import numpy as np
In [2]: A = np.random.rand(500, 500)
In [3]: timeit A[A > 0.5] = 5
100 loops, best of 3: 7.59 ms per loop
```

Comment: Note that this modifies the existing array `arr`, instead of creating a `result` array as in the OP.

Comment: Is there a way to do this by not modifying `A` but creating a new array?

Comment: What would we do, if we wanted to change values at indexes which are multiple of given n, like a[2],a[4],a[6],a[8]..... for n=2?

Comment: 100 loops, best of 3: 2.22 ms per loop

Comment: NOTE: this doesn't work if the data is in a python list, it HAS to be in a numpy array (`np.array([1,2,3]`)

Comment: @mdml np.place method is the faster than this.
timeit A[A>0.5] = 5 :- 1.79 ms ± 6.63 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each) and 
timeit np.place(A, A>0, 5) :- 732 µs ± 5.89 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

Comment: Is there a way to modify this if `arr` includes NaN values?

Comment: is it possible to use this indexing to update every value without condition? I want to do this: `array[ ? ] = x`, setting every value to x.

Secondly, is it possible to do multiple conditions like:
`array[ ? ] = 255 if array[i] > 127 else 0`

I want to optimize my code and am currently using list comprehension which was dramatically slower than this fancy indexing.

Comment: For not modifying the original array, do a deep copy of the original array. arr2 = arr.copy() and then arr2[arr2 > 255] = x

Comment: For massive arrays, this solution will likely not be workable as it creates an intermediate array in-memory equal in size to the input array. If you do not have sufficient memory on your system it will fail.

Comment: @askewchan answer of using `result = np.minimum(arr, 255)` is the best for performance in my test.

Answer (score 63):

If you want a new array `result` containing a copy of `arr` whenever `arr < 255`, and `255` otherwise:

```py
result = np.minimum(arr, 255)
```

More generally, for a lower and/or upper bound:

```py
result = np.clip(arr, 0, 255)
```

---

If you just want to access the values over 255, or something more complicated, @mtitan8's answer is more general, but `np.clip` and `np.minimum` (or `np.maximum`) are nicer and much faster for your case:

```py
In [292]: timeit np.minimum(a, 255)
100000 loops, best of 3: 19.6 µs per loop

In [293]: %%timeit
   .....: c = np.copy(a)
   .....: c[a>255] = 255
   .....: 
10000 loops, best of 3: 86.6 µs per loop
```

---

If you want to do it in-place (i.e., modify `arr` instead of creating `result`) you can use the `out` parameter of `np.minimum`:

```py
np.minimum(arr, 255, out=arr)
```

or

```py
np.clip(arr, 0, 255, arr)
```

(the `out=` name is optional since the arguments in the same order as the function's definition.)

For in-place modification, the boolean indexing speeds up a lot (without having to make and then modify the copy separately), but is still not as fast as `minimum`:

```py
In [328]: %%timeit
   .....: a = np.random.randint(0, 300, (100,100))
   .....: np.minimum(a, 255, a)
   .....: 
100000 loops, best of 3: 303 µs per loop

In [329]: %%timeit
   .....: a = np.random.randint(0, 300, (100,100))
   .....: a[a>255] = 255
   .....: 
100000 loops, best of 3: 356 µs per loop
```

---

For comparison, if you wanted to restrict your values with a minimum as well as a maximum, without `clip` you would have to do this twice, with something like

```py
np.minimum(a, 255, a)
np.maximum(a, 0, a)
```

or,

```py
a[a>255] = 255
a[a<0] = 0
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your complete comment, however np.clip and np.minimum do not seem to be what I need in this case, in the OP you see that the threshold T and the replacement value (255) are not necessarily the same number. However I still gave you an up vote for thoroughness. Thanks again.

Comment: What would we do, if we wanted to change values at indexes which are multiple of given n, like a[2],a[4],a[6],a[8]..... for n=2?

Comment: @lavee_singh, to do that, you can use the third part of the slice, which is usually neglected: `a[start:stop:step]` gives you the elements of the array from `start` to `stop`, but instead of every element, it takes only every `step` (if neglected, it is `1` by default). So to set all the evens to zero, you could do `a[::2] = 0`

Comment: Thanks I needed something, like this, even though I knew it for simple lists, but I didn't know whether or how it works for numpy.array.

Comment: Surprisingly in my investigation, `a = np.maximum(a,0)` is faster than `np.maximum(a,0,out=a)`.

Answer (score 22):

I think you can achieve this the quickest by using the `where` function:

For example looking for items greater than 0.2 in a numpy array and replacing those with 0:

```
import numpy as np

nums = np.random.rand(4,3)

print np.where(nums > 0.2, 0, nums)
```

Answer (score 16):

Another way is to use `np.place` which does in-place replacement and works with multidimentional arrays:

```
import numpy as np

# create 2x3 array with numbers 0..5
arr = np.arange(6).reshape(2, 3)

# replace 0 with -10
np.place(arr, arr == 0, -10)
```

Comment: This is the solution I used because it was the first I came across. I wonder if there is a big difference between this and the selected answer above. What do you think?

Comment: In my very limited tests, my above code with np.place is running 2X slower than accepted answer's method of direct indexing. It's surprising because I would have thought np.place would be more optimized but I guess they have probably put more work on direct indexing.

Comment: In my case  `np.place` was also slower compared to the built-in method, although the opposite is claimed in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19666626/replace-all-elements-of-python-numpy-array-that-are-greater-than-some-value#comment90115025_19666680) comment.

Answer (score 15):

You can consider using **[numpy.putmask](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.putmask.html)**:

```
np.putmask(arr, arr>=T, 255.0)
```

Here is a performance comparison with the Numpy's builtin indexing:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np
In [2]: A = np.random.rand(500, 500)

In [3]: timeit np.putmask(A, A>0.5, 5)
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.34 ms per loop

In [4]: timeit A[A > 0.5] = 5
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.82 ms per loop
```

Comment: I have tested the code for when upper limit `0.5` used instead of `5`, and `indexing` was better than  `np.putmask` about two times.

Answer (score 9):

You can also use `&`, `|` (and/or) for more flexibility:

values between 5 and 10: `A[(A>5)&(A<10)]`

values greater than 10 or smaller than 5: `A[(A<5)|(A>10)]`

Answer (score 6):

np.where() works great!

```
np.where(arr > 255, 255, arr)
```

example:

```
FF = np.array([[0, 0],
              [1, 0],
              [0, 1],
              [1, 1]])
np.where(FF == 1, '+', '-')
Out[]: 
array([['-', '-'],
       ['+', '-'],
       ['-', '+'],
       ['+', '+']], dtype='<U1')
```

Comment: np.where is a great solution, it doesn't mutate the arrays involved, and it's also directly compatible with pandas series objects. Really helped me.

Answer (score 4):

Lets us assume you have a `numpy` array that has contains the value from 0 all the way up to 20 and you want to replace numbers greater than 10 with 0

```
import numpy as np

my_arr = np.arange(0,21) # creates an array
my_arr[my_arr > 10] = 0 # modifies the value
```

> Note this will however modify the original array to avoid overwriting the original array try using `arr.copy()` to create a new detached copy of the original array and modify that instead.

```
import numpy as np

my_arr = np.arange(0,21)
my_arr_copy = my_arr.copy() # creates copy of the orignal array

my_arr_copy[my_arr_copy > 10] = 0
```