# Replace value in array when greater than x

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I get a little problem with a simple idea. I have an array of data and I would like to replace each value if the value is greater than X.

To solve that, I wrote a little script as example which give the same idea :

```
import numpy as np

# Array creation

array = np.array([0.5, 0.6, 0.9825])

print array

# If value > 0.7 replace by 0.

new_array = array[array > 0.7] == 0

print new_array
```

I would like to obtain :

```
>>> [0.5, 0.6, 0] # 0.9825 is replaced by 0 because > 0.7
```

Thank you if you could me help ;)

**EDIT :**

I didn't find How this subject could help me : [Replace all elements of Python NumPy Array that are greater than some value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19666626/replace-all-elements-of-python-numpy-array-that-are-greater-than-some-value)
The answer given by @ColonelBeauvel is not noticed in the previous post.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I wonder why this solution is not provided in the link @DonkeyKong provided:

```
np.where(arr>0.7, 0, arr)
#Out[282]: array([ 0.5,  0.6,  0. ])
```

Comment: Thank you so much ! It works very well ! I was watching `np.where` also ;)

Answer (score 1):

how about

```
a = [0.5, 0.6, 0.9825]
b = [(lambda i: 0 if i > 0.7 else i)(i) for i in a]
```

?

here is [lambda expression](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#lambda-expressions) inside [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).
check the links

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how it answers the question would significantly improve its long-term value. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation.