# Converntin NaN in a numpy array to large number(i.e. 99999)

Tags: arrays, nan

I want to replace the NaN in numpy array with a large number such as 99999.  I don't want to use numpy.nan_to_num to replace the NaN's with 0 because I want to differentiate between the NaN values and 0 values already in the dataset.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replace all elements of Python NumPy Array that are greater than some value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19666626/replace-all-elements-of-python-numpy-array-that-are-greater-than-some-value)

Comment: You can use that but change the boolean condition to `#isnan()`

Comment: x[np.isnan(x) is True] = 9999 seems only to work for me in one dimension? returning  [ [9999, .....,9999], [nan, ...., nan]].

Comment: I guess this question is different enough. One sec, I'll provide an answer.

Comment: I provided an answer, but I have `x[np.isnan(x)] = 99999` working with a 2-D array. Can you provide an example where it's not working?

Comment: That is working for me as well.  Including the 'is True' must have been the problem.  Thanks!

Comment: No worries! `is True` is almost always unnecessary.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use logical indexing to replace all `NaN`s with `99999`. You can do it like this

```
x[np.isnan(x)] = 99999
```

This does work in multiple dimensions.