# How to replace all negative numbers in an array with zero

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

If I have an NxN numpy array and if there is a negative number as any position, is there a simple and quick way I can replace that number with a 0?
something like

```
for item in array:
    if item <= 0: 
        item = 0
```

Comment: `array[array <= 0 ] = 0` should work also you say negative, shouldn't it be `array[array < 0] = 0` rather than `<=0`?

Comment: @EdChum ... it doesn't make a difference, because you end up replacing `0` with `0`. The only difference might be if the array has `float`s and some `0` have the "negative sign" while other have the positive sign, by assigning `0` you set all of them to the "positive sign", but I believe all the operations should work the same.

Comment: @Bakuriu true but there is a semantic difference here between `<0` and `<=0` with the negative statement irrespective of the end result, it's clear that `<0` means negative whilst `<=0` does not

Comment: whats wrong with the code provided? (never used numpy so i might be asking a stupid question)

Comment: @WhatsThePoint it's not vectorised and the most efficient method of setting the elements to 0, if you have a large array then you end up iterating over each row in this case whilst using a mask will set the entire array in a vectorised manner

Comment: @EdChum cheers.

Comment: @EdChum True in this case <0 is better than <=0, since I'm replacing with 0. Just a bad habit that i put <= at time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can mask the entire array by using a boolean mask, this will be much more efficient than iterating like you currently are:

```
In [41]:
array = np.random.randn(5,3)
array

Out[41]:
array([[-1.09127791,  0.51328095, -0.0300959 ],
       [ 0.62483282, -0.78287353,  1.43825556],
       [ 0.09558515, -1.96982215, -0.58196525],
       [-1.23462258,  0.95510649, -0.76008193],
       [ 0.22431534, -0.36874234, -1.46494516]])

In [42]:
array[array < 0] = 0
array

Out[42]:
array([[ 0.        ,  0.51328095,  0.        ],
       [ 0.62483282,  0.        ,  1.43825556],
       [ 0.09558515,  0.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.95510649,  0.        ],
       [ 0.22431534,  0.        ,  0.        ]])
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19666680/3334049), you can use `numpy`'s builtin indexing for this.

```
arr[arr < 0] = 0
```

Comment: how is this answer different to mine?

Comment: I hadn't seen your answer while posting mine. I won't remove mine since it adds something new which is a reference that contains explanation and benchmarking. Don't worry, though, I upvoted yours and I think it should be the selected answer for being the first one.

Comment: I don't have an issue with duplicated answers so long as it adds something new, it would be better if you added the relevant parts to your answer rather than just a link, just an observation