# Efficiently set array values to zero if not equal to a certain number?

Tags: python, arrays

I'm working in Python reading in images, and getting a 3-dimensional matrix of RGB values for pixels.

I want to take these 3-d arrays and make a matrix with only RGB values equal to r=62, g=57, b=47.

How can I do this? I've looked into masking but I don't understand how to implement this.

Edit: I'm talking about numpy arrays not lists. numpy has a lot of built in functions, for loops are pretty inefficient.

Comment: @Art I said arrays. imread from scimage.io returns a 3-d numpy array.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 that post is for lists, does it also work for 3-d numpy arrays?

Comment: That would be http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19666626/replace-all-elements-of-python-numpy-array-that-are-greater-than-some-value instead then. Next time, please provide all relevant information within your question.

Answer (score 1):

If `rgb` is a NumPy array, then this should work:

```
rgb[rgb!=[62,57,47]]=0
```