# change every value in a numpy array with a condition

Tags: python, numpy

I have a 2d array that i got from and image, for now it has 0s and 255s, I want to change all the 255s into 1s, this is a very easy task for a `for` loop.

```
for i in range(lenX):
    for j in range(lenY):
        if img[i,j]==255:
            img[i,j] = 1
```

here img is my array. I am pretty sure that there is a simpler way to do it using some kind of numpy function or something. but I looked every where I couldn't find.

If you know how to do this easily.. please help me

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19666626/replace-all-elements-of-python-numpy-array-that-are-greater-than-some-value

Comment: You shouldn't use explicit for loops like that because the operation is vectorized.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `np.where`

```
import numpy as np 

a = np.array([[1,9,1],[12,15,255],[255,1,245],[23,255,255]]) 
a = np.where(a==255, 1, a)
print(a)
```

Output:

```
[[  1   9   1]                                                                                                                                                    
 [ 12  15   1]                                                                                                                                                    
 [  1   1 245]                                                                                                                                                    
 [ 23   1   1]]
```

Answer (score 6):

This way you can modify matrix with conditions without loops

```
img[img==255]=1
```