# how to change every value in a numpy array with more than one condition

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy, multiple-conditions

i have asked something slimier before for 1  condition and it was a simple answer and works great.
[change every value in a numpy array with a condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54645172/change-every-value-in-a-numpy-array-with-a-condition)

now i am trying to find a way to do the same with two conditions.

```
 for j in range(5,45):
     # inter_data[(j*100) <= inter_data < ((j+1)*100)] = (j*100) + 50
     inter_data = np.where(((j + 1) * 100) > inter_data > (j * 100), (j * 100) + 50, inter_data)
```

i tried using the same technique and it doesn't work. seems like this can only work with one condition.

it gives the following error for two conditions

ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Comment: Check out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16343752/numpy-where-function-multiple-conditions

Comment: `a>b>c` works python scalars, but not for numpy arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
inter_data = np.where((((j + 1) * 100) > inter_data) & (inter_data > (j * 100)), (j * 100) + 50, inter_data)
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use logical and opertion `&` to do this like below using vectorizaion (with out using python loop)

```py
import numpy as np
ar = np.arange(5,45)
inter_data = np.arange(100, 100+40*100, 100)


cond = (ar+1) * 100 > inter_data
cond &= (ar) * 100 < inter_data

np.where(cond, ar*100+50, inter_data)
```