# Updating a numpy array values based on multiple conditions

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy

I have an array P as shown below:

```
P
array([[ 0.49530662,  0.32619367,  0.54593724, -0.0224462 ],
       [-0.10503237,  0.48607405,  0.28572714,  0.15175049],
       [ 0.0286128 , -0.32407902, -0.56598029, -0.26743756],
       [ 0.14353725, -0.35624814,  0.25655861, -0.09241335]])
```

and a vector `y`:

```
y
array([0, 0, 1, 0], dtype=int16)
```

I want to modify another matrix `Z` which has the same dimension as `P`, such that `Z_ij = y_j` when `Z_ij < 0`.

In the above example, my Z matrix should be

```
Z = array([[-, -, -, 0],
       [0, -, -, -],
       [-, 0, 1, 0],
       [-, 0, -, 0]])
```

Where '-' indicates the original `Z` values.  What I thought about is very straightforward implementation which basically iterates through each row of `Z` and comparing the column values against corresponding `Y` and `P`. Do you know any better pythonic/numpy approach?

Comment: Won't `np.where` work as suggested in the linked dup of your previous question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55947579/?

Comment: Now got it cleared.  Just now realizing it works as a if else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is `np.where`. This is how to use it:-

```
import numpy as np
z = np.array([[ 0.49530662,  0.32619367,  0.54593724, -0.0224462 ],
       [-0.10503237,  0.48607405,  0.28572714,  0.15175049],
       [ 0.0286128 , -0.32407902, -0.56598029, -0.26743756],
       [ 0.14353725, -0.35624814,  0.25655861, -0.09241335]])
y=([0, 0, 1, 0])
result = np.where(z<0,y,z)
#Where z<0, replace it by y
```

## Result

```
>>> print(result)
[[0.49530662 0.32619367 0.54593724 0.        ]
 [0.         0.48607405 0.28572714 0.15175049]
 [0.0286128  0.         1.         0.        ]
 [0.14353725 0.         0.25655861 0.        ]]
```