# How to replace elements in python array using numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix

so I am working on finding the sigmoid equation for logistic regression for matrices. I have two matrices, z and g, and would like to replace the values in g with the sigmoid values. I have the following code, but cannot figure out how to replace the elements in g with its respective sigmoid value. Any help would be appreciated!

I have the following:

```
z = np.array([[1, 4, 5, 12], [-5, 8, 9, 10], [-6, 7, 11, 19]])
g = np.zeros(z.shape)
for row in z:
    for i in row:       
    sigmoid = 1/(1+np.exp(-i))
```

Comment: Question has in fact nothing to do with `machine-learning`, kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).

Comment: check this out <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19666626/replace-all-elements-of-python-numpy-array-that-are-greater-than-some-value>?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it without a loop:

```
z = np.array([[1, 4, 5, 12], [-5, 8, 9, 10], [-6, 7, 11, 19]])
g = 1/(1+np.exp(-z))
```