# How to replace values in numpy array at the same time

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have `numpy` array with random numbers. For example like this
`[7 1 2 0 2 3 4 0 5]`
and I want to replace every number at the same time if number from this array = 7, I want to replace it with 2 , also if number = 2, replace it with 3. So it will be like `[2 1 3 0 3 3 4 0 5]` . I have tried it with `np.where` but can't change any of them.

Comment: what does your code look like?

Comment: Have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19666680/10940584) - you would probably have to run two replace operations, so maybe something like `myarray[myarray == 2] = 3` then `myarray[myarray == 7] = 2` so that the values changed by the second condition aren't altered by the first replacement (unless that is the intent).

Comment: @Chris Hello. I am trying to write code that work like this tool https://sndeep.info/en/tools/checksum_calculator . And in the second section I have to change values.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's better to use [np.select](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) if you've multiple conditions:

```
a = np.array([7, 1, 2, 0, 2, 3, 4, 0, 5])
a = np.select([a == 7, a == 2], [2, 3], a)
```

##### OUTPUT:

```
[2 1 3 0 3 3 4 0 5]
```

Comment: Thank you @Nk03 for your answer. What if when this array is generated randomly and I have formula for number change? I mean I want to do multiple changes but not always know which number will be first my be `7` will be second , so it will be replaced with 3 that I do not want that. I hope you understand what I mean.

Comment: I'm hardcoding both the values here. If you want `dynamic` values **don't** `hardcode` the values and replace them with suitable formula.

Comment: short and precise.

Answer (score 2):

Numpy provide the comparison to a scalar with the standard `==` operator, such that `arr == v` return a boolean array. Taking `arr[arr == v]` takes the subset (or slice) of `arr` where the condition is met so this snippet should work.

```py
import numpy as np
arr = np.array([7, 1, 2, 0, 2, 3, 4, 0, 5])
arr[arr == 7] = 2
arr
array([2, 1, 2, 0, 2, 3, 4, 0, 5])
```

Comment: what if I have multiple numbers to change , not two of them but every number in given array with some formula ? Thank you.