# if i have two image masks as numpy arrays, how do i overlay them ontop of each other. taking into account overlapping and non overlapping areas

Tags: python, numpy-ndarray

[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aWdb8.png)

the pixel values are 0 for background and 2 for white area

[Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/drQPp.png)

the pixel values are 0 for background and 1 for white area

how do i combine them to a new image 3 such that
-every area in image 2 that is pixel value 0 remains 0 in new image
-every area in image 2 that is pixel value 1 remains 1
-every area in image 1 that is pixel value 2 remains 2 in new image (including areas that are 1 in image 2)

Basically the output should look similar to the one below

[Image 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BzBNA.png)

I used the | method in python since im dealing with ndarrays (h,w)
image3=img1|img2

Im getting new pixel values ranging from 0 1 2 and 3
What i want is only 0, 1 and 2
All images are displayed using plt.imshow(img, cmap="gray") which is why they look contrasted.

Answer (score 0):

If the 2 Images are the same size i would add them both together and then replace all 3s by 2s.

Comment: how can i convert all 3's to 2's?

Comment: I haven't worked with numpy for a while. Maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19666626/replace-all-elements-of-python-numpy-array-that-are-greater-than-some-value

Comment: Thank you soo much
The link was very helpful
For future reference this can be used to convert pixels
arr[arr > 255] = x